# AngularJS - Creating a compile function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a custom compile function, to make it easier to dynamically add HTML to a page.

The argument htmlStr is the incoming HTML to compile. The argument value is a variable that can be added to the scope. The argument compiledHTMLFunc is a function that will be executed with the compiled object. Here's my code:

```
function compileHTML (htmlStr, value, compiledHTMLFunc)
{
    var $injector = angular.injector (["ng", "angularApp"]);
    $injector.invoke (function ($rootScope, $compile)
        {
            $rootScope.value = value;
            var obj = angular.element (htmlStr);
            var obj2 = $compile (obj)($rootScope);

            if (compiledHTMLFunc != null)
                compiledHTMLFunc (obj2);
        });
}
```

Here's how I use the function:

```
compileHTML ("<button class = \"btn btn-primary\">{{ value }}</button>", "Ok", function (element)
    {
        $(document.body).append (element);
    });
```

Whenever I try to compile the following HTML, the inline {{ value }} doesn't get compiled. Even if I simply change it to {{ 1+1 }}. Why is this?

**Update:** I dunno why I didn't create a fiddle earlier, here's an example: http://jsbin.com/vuxazuzu/1/edit

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I just did, sorry about not including that sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be pretty simple. Since you invoke compiler from outside of angular digest cycle you have to invoke it manually to boost the process, for example by wrapping `compiledHTMLFunc` into `$timeout` service call:

```
function compileHTML (htmlStr, scope, compiledHTMLFunc) {
    var $injector = angular.injector(["ng", "angularApp"]);
    $injector.invoke(function($rootScope, $compile, $timeout) {
        $rootScope = angular.extend($rootScope, scope);
        var obj = $compile(htmlStr)($rootScope);
        if (compiledHTMLFunc != null) {
            $timeout(function() {
                compiledHTMLFunc(obj);
            });
        }
    });
}

compileHTML('<button class="btn btn-primary">{{value}}</button>', {value: 'Ok'}, function(element) {
    angular.element(document.body).append(element);
});
```

I also improved your code a little. Note how now `compileHTML` accepts an object instead of single value. It adds more flexibility, so now you can use multiple values in template.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/IAPhQ9i9aVVBwV9MuAIE?p=preview

And here is your updated demo: http://jsbin.com/vuxazuzu/2/edit

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks so much! More specifically what did the trick was using $timeout. I loved your idea with integrating objects into the root scope. I'm assuming angular.extend performs a deep copy of the scope object?

Comment: No, `angular.extend` performs shallow copy. But if you use jQuery angular.extend will become `$.extend` which can perform deep copying as well.

Comment: Oh, ok. I gotcha. Thank you very much for your help and comments!